# Мигрировать с Mysql на postgresql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, миграция

Прошу помочь с переносом базы данных с mysql на postgres. Подскажите есть ли быстрый такой способ через программы или сервисы? Мне нужно перенести все таблицы, процедуры и функции с mysql, чтобы работали на postgres. Дело в том, что сама программа использует процедуры

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetLoansHistory`(IN PUserId int)

BEGIN

  DECLARE PositionId int(11);

 

  SET PositionId = (SELECT

      u.positionId

    FROM users u

    WHERE u.id = PUserId);

 

  CASE

    -- Если КП

    WHEN PositionId IN (8, 14) THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

        AND l.startDateTime > CURDATE())

        OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41)))

        AND l.filialId IN (SELECT

            u.filialId

          FROM users u

          WHERE u.id = PUserId)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId = 3 THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND (l.statusId NOT IN (13, 13, 33, 41)

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id))) -- (l.typeId = 3 and l.startDateTime > CURDATE()) OR -- AND l.statusId NOT IN (13,27,13,33,41)

        AND l.filialId IN (SELECT

            u.filialId

          FROM users u

          WHERE u.id = PUserId)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId = 7 THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId IN (4, 5, 6)

        AND (l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41))

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)))

        -- AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (9, 10) THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId IN (1, 2)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 27, 33, 41))

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id))

        -- AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (19, 21) THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

          INNER JOIN kbresponsibleusers k

            ON k.bin = l.bin

            AND k.userType = 1

        WHERE l.startDateTime > CURDATE()

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (20, 22) THEN SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = 0

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

          INNER JOIN kbresponsibleusers k

            ON k.bin = l.bin

            AND k.userType = 2

        WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

        AND l.startDateTime > CURDATE())

        OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41)))

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    ELSE SELECT

        l.id,

        f.name AS filialName,

        r.Name AS typeName,

        l.startDateTime,

        l.companyName,

        l.BIN,

        l.loanNumber,

        s.name AS statusName,

        l.comments,

        l.summ,

        lastUser.name AS lastUser

      FROM loanrequest l

        INNER JOIN requesttype r

          ON l.typeId = r.Id

        INNER JOIN statuses s

          ON l.statusId = s.id

        INNER JOIN segments s1

          ON l.segmentId = s1.id

        INNER JOIN filials f

          ON l.filialId = f.id

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT

            l.loanId,

            l.userId

          FROM loanusers l

          WHERE l.isFinished = 0

          GROUP BY l.loanId,

                   l.userId) AS lastLu

          ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

        LEFT JOIN users lastUser

          ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

      WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

      AND l.startDateTime > CURDATE())

      OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

      AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 27, 13, 33, 41)))

      AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

      ORDER BY l.id DESC;

  END CASE;

END
```

НОВОЕ

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getloanshistory(

                puserid integer)

    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, filialname character varying, typename character varying, startdatetime date, companyname text, bin text, loannumber text, statusname character varying, comments text, summ double precision, lastuser character varying)

    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100

    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE

    ROWS 1000

 

AS $BODY$

DECLARE

  PositionId iNT;

BEGIN

 

  PositionId := (SELECT u.positionId FROM users u WHERE u.id = PUserId);

 

  CASE

    -- Если КП

    WHEN PositionId IN (8, 14) THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished= b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

        AND l.startDateTime > current_date)

        OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41)))

        AND l.filialId IN (SELECT

            u.filialId

          FROM users u

          WHERE u.id = PUserId)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId = 3 THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND (l.statusId NOT IN (13, 13, 33, 41)

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id))) -- (l.typeId = 3 and l.startDateTime > CURDATE()) OR -- AND l.statusId NOT IN (13,27,13,33,41)

        AND l.filialId IN (SELECT

            u.filialId

          FROM users u

          WHERE u.id = PUserId)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId = 7 THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId IN (4, 5, 6)

        AND (l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41))

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)))

        -- AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (9, 10) THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

        WHERE ((l.typeId IN (1, 2)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 27, 33, 41))

        OR PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id))

        -- AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (19, 21) THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished = b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

          INNER JOIN kbresponsibleusers k

            ON k.bin = l.bin

            AND k.userType = 1

        WHERE l.startDateTime > current_date

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    WHEN PositionId IN (20, 22) THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT

          l.id,

          f.name AS filialName,

          r.Name AS typeName,

          l.startDateTime,

          l.companyName,

          l.BIN,

          l.loanNumber,

          s.name AS statusName,

          l.comments,

          l.summ,

          lastUser.name AS lastUser

        FROM loanrequest l

          INNER JOIN requesttype r

            ON l.typeId = r.Id

          INNER JOIN statuses s

            ON l.statusId = s.id

          INNER JOIN segments s1

            ON l.segmentId = s1.id

          INNER JOIN filials f

            ON l.filialId = f.id

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT

              l.loanId,

              l.userId

            FROM loanusers l

            WHERE l.isFinished= b'0'

            GROUP BY l.loanId,

                     l.userId) AS lastLu

            ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

          LEFT JOIN users lastUser

            ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

          INNER JOIN kbresponsibleusers k

            ON k.bin = l.bin

            AND k.userType = 2

        WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

        AND l.startDateTime > current_date)

        OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

        AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 41)))

        ORDER BY l.id DESC;

    ELSE RETURN QUERY SELECT

        l.id,

        f.name AS filialName,

        r.Name AS typeName,

        l.startDateTime,

        l.companyName,

        l.BIN,

        l.loanNumber,

        s.name AS statusName,

        l.comments,

        l.summ,

        lastUser.name AS lastUser

      FROM loanrequest l

        INNER JOIN requesttype r

          ON l.typeId = r.Id

        INNER JOIN statuses s

          ON l.statusId = s.id

        INNER JOIN segments s1

          ON l.segmentId = s1.id

        INNER JOIN filials f

          ON l.filialId = f.id

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT

            l.loanId,

            l.userId

          FROM loanusers l

          WHERE l.isFinished = b'0'

          GROUP BY l.loanId,

                   l.userId) AS lastLu

          ON lastLu.loanId = l.id

        LEFT JOIN users lastUser

          ON lastUser.id = lastLu.userId

      WHERE ((l.typeId = 3

      AND l.startDateTime > current_date)

      OR (l.typeId NOT IN (3)

      AND l.statusId NOT IN (13, 27, 13, 33, 41)))

      AND PUserId IN (l.ka2Id, l.checkerId, l.ka1Id)

      ORDER BY l.id DESC;

  END CASE;

END;

$BODY$;

 

ALTER FUNCTION public.getloanshistory(integer)

    OWNER TO postgres;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Половину придётся переписывать - слишком непохожи синтаксисы. Нет, простейшие вещи переносятся, есть такие программный средства... но как только что хоть минимально нестандарт - всё, напильник в руки.

Comment: в основном смог сами таблицы перенести вручную, но проблема с процедурами. Я вот только не знаю одно, что у меня в mysql есть и процедуры, и функции, а вот в postgre вместо процедур использовать функции, но что теперь делать с функциями?

Comment: ВЫ просто напрашиваетесь на закрытие вопроса по причинам номер 4 и 5. Не пытайтесь охватить всё сразу. Функцию? ну так помещаете в вопрос конкретную функцию на 2-3 строки, пример её использования (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO, запрос с её использованием, результат) и спрашиваете, как сделать то же. но в MySQL. А далее по образу и подобию....

Comment: Хорошо, я разберусь, если нету более легких способов, но могу получить помощь по скрипту выше. Дальше от него буду отталкиваться

Comment: А какие проблемы с этим скриптом? он уже в синтаксисе MySQL, и на взгляд по касательной - нормальный.

Comment: Я его пробовал запустить на postgressql. В основном было куча ошибок в синтаксисе, которые более-менее исправил, но процедура не может вернуть. Там была ошибка что-то про назначение. Сейчас пишу как функцию, но не могу вернуть несколько столбцов. "В запросе нет назначения для данных результата" HINT Если вам нужно отбросить результаты select, используйте perform

Answer (score 0):

Пример конвертации процедуры MySQL в функцию PostgreSQL. Я постарался сделать её похожей по используемым конструкциям.

Исходная MySQL функция:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE select_partial (param1 INT, param2 INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE min_value INT;
  DECLARE max_value INT;
  SET min_value = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test WHERE val = param1);
  SET max_value = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test WHERE val = param1);
  CASE WHEN param2 IN (1,3)
       THEN SELECT * FROM test WHERE id < max_value;
       WHEN param2 = 2
       THEN SELECT * FROM test WHERE id >= min_value;
       ELSE SELECT * FROM test WHERE id BETWEEN min_value AND max_value;
  END CASE;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nle7sknp)

Аналогичная PostgreSQL функция:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION select_partial (param1 integer, param2 integer)
RETURNS TABLE (id INT, val INT)
AS $$
DECLARE
  min_value INT;
  max_value INT;
BEGIN
  min_value := (SELECT MIN(test.id) FROM test WHERE test.val = param1);
  max_value := (SELECT MAX(test.id) FROM test WHERE test.val = param1);
  CASE WHEN param2 IN (1,3)
       THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.id < max_value;
       WHEN param2 = 2
       THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.id >= min_value;
       ELSE RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.id BETWEEN min_value AND max_value;
  END CASE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9ZGAsuZ)

Comment: Я до этого что-то похожее делал. Выводит такое же сообщение. Спасибо за подсказку. Я выше приложил свой скрипт

Comment: @ЕрланСакан *"В запросе нет назначения для данных результата"* Обратите внимание на `RETURNS TABLE` и `RETURN QUERY`. Именно они отвечают за возврат набора записей.

Comment: я обновил вопрос. там указал свой скрипт. там просто ничего не выводит как на скриншоте.

Comment: @ЕрланСакан *там указал свой скрипт. там просто ничего не выводит как на скриншоте* Значит, где-то косяк. Метод сам по  себе - работает. Если не работает в конкретном применении - либо косяк в применении метода (для чего синтаксически вроде бы нет предпосылок), либо данные таковы, что выполняемый запрос не возвращает записей. Отлаживайте - никто, кроме Вас, этим заниматься не будет.

Comment: это понятно, что мой косяк. но я уже куча раз пытался. я только начал работать с postgres и сюда пришел за подсказкой. большую часть кода написал, но не знаю как исправить. если она заработала бы, то от нее отталкивался бы

Comment: @ЕрланСакан Отлаживайте кусками. Проверьте, что функция выполняется (вставьте в неё простое `RETURN QUERY SELECT 1 output;`). Проверьте, что каждый отдельный SELECT выполняется (вставьте в функцию только один запрос). Проверьте, что CASE отрабатывает правильно (вставьте его с простыми запросами). Ибо на приведённой, извините, "лапше" отлаживаться совершенно невозможно.

Comment: хорошо. спасибо за уделенное время. а вообще было бы хорошо получить скрипт нескольких таблиц с объединением без * в select

Answer (score 0):

Не в качестве рекламы, а работы для: https://www.fishcodelib.com/DBMigration.htm

Если база не слишком сложная - поможет, хотя в любом случае потребуется допиливать результат. Еще можно посоветовать EMS MySQL / PostgreSQL Manager. В части штатной работы вполне себе достойная вещь, но только под Windows ну и без конкретных косяков не обходится. И для серверов Postgre до 11 включительно, выше они не работают, ленятся.